# In Python, write a script that determines whether or not a user-inputted number is a prime number

Tags: python

Write a script that determines whether or not a user-inputted number is a prime number and prints "The number that you inputted is a prime number" or "The number that you inputted is not a prime number" depending on what your script finds.

I have code that is failing some of the test cases and I'm not sure why. I see some answers on here that involve calculate the sqrt, but I don't understand why that'd be beneficial.

```
num= int(input())

if num == 0 or num ==1:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
while num < 0:
    break
if num > 0:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
            break
        else:
            print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
            break
```

The code is always right when I try it with a few test cases, but it isn't passing my homework assignment.

Comment: " I see some answers on here that involve calculate the sqrt, but I don't understand why that'd be beneficial" - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composite_Number_has_Prime_Factor_not_Greater_Than_its_Square_Root

Comment: The reason for the square root is efficiency. Take the number 16 for example, which has the factors (1, 16), (2, 8), (4, 4), (8,2), (16,1). Since the square root of 16 is 4, testing any numbers beyond is redundant.

Comment: In addition, you don't need to test any number that is not a prime. Since 4 is a factor of 2 and 2, testing 2 and 4 and 8 for that matter are redundant as well. For this problem that may not help much but you can at least ignore the even numbers outside of 2.

Comment: Checking only odd numbers and up to the square root of the candidate is a good start. The last optimisation you could consider making is that odd primes > 3 are always of the form (6k ± 1) for integer k, since 6k, 6k ± 2 and 6k ± 4 are even, 6k ± 3 is divisible by 3 and 6k + 5 ≡ 6k - 1.

Comment: Note: Trial division is slow if there are no small prime factors. Baillie-PSW is currently the best approach (guaranteed results for small numbers, and no known counterexamples even for large numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong; you should break only if the condition evaluates to `True`, since you need to test all numbers up to `num ** 0.5` (`num` in your code). 9 is an example of a non-prime number that your code evaluates as prime.

You want something like this:

```
prime = True
if num > 0:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num % i == 0:
            prime = False
            break

    if prime:
        print(f'{num} is a prime number.')

    else:
        print(f'{num} is not a prime number.')
```

By setting `prime` to `True` at the start and changing it to `False` only if a factor is found, we can tell, after evaluation of the condition for all the values of `i`, if the number is prime.

Comment: Ah! Ninja'd. :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in the logic below:

```
for i in range(2,num):
    if num%i==0:
        print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
        break
    else:
        print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
        break
```

To see where the issue occurs, try using your code to check if `9` is prime.
Your `for` loop does the following:

1. `i = 2`
2. `if num % i == 0`, not prime, break.
3. `else`, prime, break.

This means that your `for` loop is guaranteed to stop at `i==2`.
In other words, your definition for a prime number, according to this algorithm is 'any odd number'.

To fix this, you need to find a way to allow the loop to iterate between all the remaining possible divisors, without breaking after the first iteration.

I'm going to stop there, to give you a chance to see if you can figure the rest out yourself. If you can't make any progress, let me know, and I'll give another hint.